# Rails has many through error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Seems I've defined the source as the AR error message suggests, but still getting errors. Any idea? Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.9.2

```
    class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :participations
      has_many :users, :through => :participations

      has_many :editing_sessions
      has_many :editors, :through => :editing_sessions, :source => :users
    end


    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :participations
      has_many :documents , :through => :participations

      has_many :editing_sessions
      has_many :open_documents, :through => :editing_sessions, :source => :documents
    end


    class EditingSession < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :users
      belongs_to :documents
    end

    create_table "editing_sessions", :force => true do |t|
      t.integer  "user_id"
      t.integer  "document_id"

      t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
      t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
    end


    Console:

    u = User.first
    => ... OK

    u.editing_sessions
    => []

    u.open_documents
    => ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) :document in model EditingSession. Try 'has_many :open_documents, :through => :editing_sessions, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :users or :documents?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the EditingSession definition so that the belongs_to labels are in the singular form:

```
class EditingSession < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :document
end
```

But leave the other source definitions in the Document and Users classes in the plural form (i.e. `:source => :users` and `:source => :documents`)

Thats the convention in the [Ruby on Rails Has-Many-Through Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue! It was not obvious to me. What logic am I missing?

Comment: Since the association in the Documents class is a "has_many" rails assumes that it should be in the plural form, which is why it should be source=>:documents. However, since the EditingSession uses's a "belongs_to" it can only belong to one document, so rails assumes that there should be a field named ":document".

Comment: Also, in the error, it says "Could not find the source association(s) :document". The whole convention takes a little getting used to.